# Installing MySQL via Ansible (Debian)

Tags: mysql, ansible, debian

I'm trying to use Ansible to install MySQL onto a Debian server, but I'm having trouble, despite having read several guides to this, and looked at some questions here. Furthermore, I wrote a test case, and of course works perfectly and I can't understand the effective difference.

My intended version is a separate mysql.yml task that's included in a larger role. I'd prefer not to use a .my.cnf file, and I'm not clear whether or not that's strictly necessary (I don't use this in my normal installations, I enter passwords in other ways) but in any case, it's failing to work in a yet different way. The initial part of this task looks like this (the stuff running beforehand is not obviously relevant--installing SSH keys, fetching a few files, etc.):

```
- name: include variable file for MySQL
  include_vars:
      file: mysql.yml

- name: Set MySQL root password before installing
  debconf: name='mysql-server' question='mysql-server/root_password' value='{{MySQL_root_pass | quote}}' vtype='password'
  become: yes

- name: Confirm MySQL root password before installing
  debconf: name='mysql-server' question='mysql-server/root_password_again' value='{{MySQL_root_pass | quote}}' vtype='password'
  become: yes

- name: Install MySQL packages.
  apt: name="{{item}}" state=present
  become: yes
  with_items:
     - default-mysql-server
     - default-mysql-client
     - python3-mysqldb
     - python-mysqldb
     - libdbd-mysql-perl

- name: Create a user for the 'library' db
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: '{{ MySQL_root_pass | quote }}'
    name: '{{ library_login_user }}'
    password: '{{ library_login_pw }}'
    priv: 'library.*:ALL,GRANT'
    state: present
```

This results in the following output:

```
TASK [common : include variable file for MySQL] ********************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [common : Set MySQL root password before installing] **********************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [common : Confirm MySQL root password before installing] ******************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [common : Install MySQL packages.] ****************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'default-mysql-server', u'default-mysql-client', u'python3-mysqldb', u'python-mysqldb', u'libdbd-mysql-perl'])

TASK [common : Create a user for the 'library' db] *****************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /home/testuser/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1698, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'\")"}
```

What I don't understand is that when I try to manually log into the MySQL server as root, it won't let me--I get an "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'" error, whether I use the password I have in the variable file, or a blank password. So I'm stuck with a MySQL install that I can't actually use.

On the other hand, I wrote an isolated test playbook, with almost identical code, but just installing the MySQL packages (and not the other few), and when I run this, I *am* able to log in as root to the server, using the password set in the playbook:

```
- name: install MySQL (only)
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    MySQL_root_pass: foobar
  tasks:

    - name: Set MySQL root password before installing
      debconf: name='mysql-server' question='mysql-server/root_password' value='{{MySQL_root_pass | quote}}' vtype='password'
      become: yes

    - name: Confirm MySQL root password before installing
      debconf: name='mysql-server' question='mysql-server/root_password_again' value='{{MySQL_root_pass | quote}}' vtype='password'
      become: yes

    - name: Install MySQL packages.
      apt: name="{{item}}" state=present
      become: yes
      with_items:
         - default-mysql-server
         - default-mysql-client
```

(That version can run exactly as written.)

What is the right way to do this? Any why is my original version failing in a way that the test-case version is not? In all cases, I'm installing onto a VM that I reset to its initial-installation snapshot before I run Ansible, so there's nothing that's getting left behind from a previous run.

Comment: "*when I try to manually log into the MySQL server as root, it won't let me*" - "*I am able to log in as root to the server*" ー show that instead of describing. Everything works if you execute from the `root` account.

Comment: Can you show the output when run with verbose output?  Does the MySQL service need to be started after you install? (I don't use Debian) Can you test with the use of a simple password that shouldn't need to be quoted (ex: 1234_Ab-Cd), or hard-code it into a playbook for testing then move to variables in a later revision.

Answer (score 0):

If using debian packages with Stretch, take in account that authentication goes through OS user:

https://wiki.debian.org/MySql

regards,